# Can't get a simple JUnit4 test to run from the command line

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I have an ant build that compiles a JUnit test file file in`src...test` and copies it to `build/timex...com/visualpatterns/timex/test` (I've written the complete path name below).  But for the life of me, I can't get JUnit to run the thing.  Can anyone point me in the right direction (I've wasted hrs on this)?  My `CLASSPATH` seems to be ok (JUnit runs), but it can't find the class file...

```
$ echo $CLASSPATH
**.;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip;C:\Program Files\junit4.8.2\junit-4.8.2.jar;C:\Program Files\junit4.8.2**


Me@My-PC /cygdrive/c/java/Code/Command_Line/Projects/timex
$ **java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore**
JUnit version 4.8.2

Time: 0.001

OK (0 tests)


Me@My-PC /cygdrive/c/java/Code/Command_Line/Projects/timex
$ **java -cp build/timex/WEB-INF/classes org.junit.runner.JUnitCore  com.visualpatterns.timex.test.SimpleTest**
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/runner/JUnitCore
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.runner.JUnitCore
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.  Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main"
```

---

```
/cygdrive/c/java/Code/Command_Line/Projects/timex/
------------------------------------------------------

   **build/timex/WEB-INF/classes/com/visualpatterns/timex/test/***SimpleTest.class*
```

**SimpleTest.java**

```
package com.visualpatterns.timex.test;

import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

public class SimpleTest
{

 int value1 = 2, value2 = 3, expectedResult = 5;

    @Test
    public void addSuccess()
    {
        assertTrue(value1 + value2 == expectedResult);
    }

    @Test
    public void addFail()
    {
        assertTrue(value1 - value2 == expectedResult);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your second execution you are changing the classpath with `-cp`. This is okay if you want to add new entries to the classpath but in your case you are replacing the old classpath which got the junit library. That's why it cannot found the junit class anymore (`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/runner/JUnitCore`). You have to use something like that:

```
$ echo $CLASSPATH
.;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip;C:\Program Files\junit4.8.2\junit-4.8.2.jar;C:\Program Files\junit4.8.2
(to verify the classpath for junit)
$ java -cp $CLASSPATH;build/timex/WEB-INF/classes org.junit.runner.JUnitCore com.visualpatterns.timex.test.SimpleTest
(separate new classpath entries with ; )
```

See also [PATH and CLASSPATH](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) and [Setting the class path](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/classpath.html) (first google hits).

Answer (score 0):

You don't run JUnit from the command line like that. The tests don't have a `main` method, so are not executable.

If you used Ant to compile the source, then you should use Ant to run the tests also.

See the [JUnit section of the Ant manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html).

Comment: I used the build.xml from the book (Agile Java Development With Spring, Hibernate And Eclipse) -- don't really know Ant yet.  I was trying to start from the ground up...maybe I should just learn Ant now.  Thanks.

Comment: @user511808: In that case, I strongly suggest starting with a proper development environment instead (e.g. Eclipse/NetBeans/IntelliJ), rather than groping about with command lines.

Comment: While tests don't have a `main` method, `JUnitCore` does (see http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/JUnitCore.html#main(java.lang.String...)). I do agree if you use Ant to do the build you should use the JUnit Ant task.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just use [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) to run your Junit tests. It's faster than using Ant. The latter however is more portable. In Eclipse simply key in the keyboard shortcut Alt+Shift+X+T to run your unit test.

Comment: 'alt shift x t?  what is this emacs :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all!! (and a special shout-out to Progman).  The problem was putting single quotes around the class argument (I'm using Cygwin).

Me@My-PC /cygdrive/c/java/Code/Command_Line/Projects/timex
$ java -cp '$CLASSPATH;C:\Program Files\junit4.8.2\junit-4.8.2.jar;C:\Program Files\junit4.8.2;build/timex/WEB-INF/classes' org.junit.runner.JUnitCore com.visualpatterns.timex.test.SimpleTest

As far as Eclipse/Ant goes, that's too easy ;-).  I think you learn more when you start with the command line instead of having automation doing it all, kinda like reading a map vs. using a GPS.  Once I get this little web arch/app going, I'll switch to Eclipse to save time, but for know I prefer to learn a bit more (and make dumb mistakes).

Me@My-PC /cygdrive/c/java/Code/Command_Line/Projects/timex
$ java -cp '$CLASSPATH;C:\Program Files\junit4.8.2\junit-4.8.2.jar;C:\Program Files\junit4.8.2;build/timex/WEB-INF/classes' org.junit.runner.JUnitCore com.visualpatterns.timex.test.SimpleTest